# Chain elements in matrix using rows

Tags: arrays, matlab, list, matrix

I have a matrix where each row is a combination of two numbers, like `A = [1 2; 2 5; 3 4; 4 6; 5 6]`

`A` is built so that, for each row, the first elements is always smaller than the second one.

I need to return, from `A`, the lists of chained elements (in the case above, the lists of chained elements are `1 2 5 6` and `3 4 6`). These lists are essentially built by considering a row, and checking is the last number is the first number of another row. Do you have any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: Simple: `for` loop. Loop through each row, check condition ? add to chain : move on. I'll leave the efficient solution up to you.

Comment: What if there are "loops" in the data? For example, what would the output be for input `[1     2;
     3     4;
     2     5;
     5     6;
     4     3];`?
`

Comment: @LuisMendo: tha matrix is built so that, for each row, the first number is always smaller than the second one. But there are cases like `[1 2; 3 4; 2 5; 4 6; 5 6]`, from which I would like to get two groups: `1 2 5 6` and `3 4 6`.

Comment: @albus_c Got it. You should include that in the question to make it clear

Comment: @LuisMendo OK. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work. It builds a matrix (`B`) that tells which elements are connected (by 1 step). It then extends that matrix ( `C`) to include 0-step, 1-step, ..., (`n-1`)-step connections, where `n` is the number of nodes.

From that matrix, groups of connected elements are obtained (`R`). Finally, only "maximal" groups are kept (that is, those, not contained in other groups).

```
A = [1 2; 3 4; 2 5; 4 6; 5 6]; %// data
n = max(A(:)); 
B = full(sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), 1, n, n )); %// matrix of 1-step connections
C = eye(n) | B; %// initiallize with 0-step and 1-step connections
for k = 1:n-1
    C = C | C*B; %// add k-step connections, up to k=n-1
end
[ii, jj] = find(C);
R = accumarray(ii, jj, [], @(x) {sort(x).'}); %'// all groups (maximal or not)
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(1:n);
C = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x, y)), R(xx), R(yy) ); %// group included in another?
result = R(all(~C | eye(n), 2)); %// keep only groups that are not included in others
```

This gives

```
>> result{:}
ans =
     1     2     5     6
ans =
     3     4     6
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for that

Answer (score 4):

If I got the question correctly, assuming `A` as the input array, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
mask = bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),A(:,2).');
out = unique(A(any(mask,1).' | any(mask,2),:))
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2
     3     4
     2     5
     5     6
>> mask = bsxfun(@eq,A(:,1),A(:,2).');
>> unique(A(any(mask,1).' | any(mask,2),:))
ans =
     1
     2
     5
     6
```

---

You can also use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html), like so -

```
out = unique(A(ismember(A(:,1),A(:,2)) | ismember(A(:,2),A(:,1)),:))
```

---

Third option would be to use [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) to solve it, like so -

```
[~,idx1,idx2] = intersect(A(:,1),A(:,2));
out = unique(A([idx1,idx2],:))
```

Comment: What if I have a case like `A = [1 2; 3 4; 2 5; 4 6; 5 6]` , from which I would like to get two groups: `1 2 5 6` and `3 4 6`?